# How to fetch "What are you doing" part in Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

I tried with all the parameters(scopes) in the feed section in [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1) but couldn't able to retrieve "**What are you doing**" part in Facebook? Refer below image for details.
[image]

As you could see from the above image, I could retrieve the status as "**message**" parameter in GraphAPI link but couldn't able to retrieve "**feeling crazy**" part in my status. Refer the below image on how am retrieving status by passing parameters.

[image]

Checking scopes like messaging, caption, name I could get the other parts of my status but couldn't retrieve Feeling Crazy part? What is the parameter to get that particular detail? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not available in the API

Comment: @WizKid Are you sure?

Comment: Yes I am. And Stackoverflow forces me to type a bunch of characters